# Switch properly from HTML website to WordPress without hurting Google rankings

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, html, migration

I'm about to switch my current HTML website to WordPress. My website has been up since 2006. I think my situation is pretty standard.  Here are the main details of the transition:

- My current site is in the `/public` folder
- Most pages have `.php` extension
- The WordPress folder is `/clickandbuilds/mywebsite` (WordPress.org, hosted by 1&1)
- I'll also need to do 301 redirects for all `.php` pages to the WP pages

Is it safe to just switch my domain from the /public folder to the WordPress folder once everything is ready? I assume it's a standard procedure - but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all of the '/foopage.php' pages have 301 redirects to their new slugs '/foopage', and the domain name is the same, then: yes.